# Outlook Add In crash report

Tags: crash, outlook, add-in

If there is a crash of an Outlook Add In and the exception is unhandled, is there a way to obtain crash log data for that particular Add In?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. I'd suggest handling exceptions in the code. Also I'd recommend creating a log file for each add-in run and write all operations there. It will help you to diagnose the issue.

You can check [this](http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx) source for more info on VSTO logging and alerts, but in essence you change two environment variable values depending on what you need to do:

> **Displaying VSTO Alert Prompts**
>
> To display each error in a message box, set the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS variable to 0 (zero). You can suppress the messages by setting the variable to 1 (one).
>
> **Logging VSTO Alerts to a Log file**
>
> To write the errors to a log file, set the VSTO_LOGALERTS variable to 1 (one).
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Office creates the log file in the folder that contains the application manifest. The default name is .manifest.log. To stop logging errors, set the variable to 0 (zero).

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.